# Can supervisord show a tail of stderr in its web interface?

Tags: supervisord

Can supervisord show a tail of a proccess' stderr in its built-in web interface?

Only stdout appears immediately available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although the web interface doesn't link to it, you *can* switch channels on the logtail; the default is `stdout` but you can also ask for the `stderr` logtail by altering the logtail URL.

Normally the url for the `tail -f` function takes the form of `/logtail/processname`, but it supports adding the channel as an extra path element. Thus, `/logtail/processname/stdout` is the same as leaving off the channel, or you could switch to `/logtail/processname/stderr` for tailing the stderr log.

Comment: Perfect! Now to get a patch in to supervisord to have it in the web interface.